# Can't locate an XML file inside a META-INF directory

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, xfire

I've set up a web service I'm trying to debug in Eclipse.

It has a directory structure like this:

> Root /
>      + src
>      + META-INF
>      + WEB-INF

Inside the `META-INF` directory, there is a folder `\xfire\services.xml`.

When I start the server, I have the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/xfire/services.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

When I run `procmon.exe` from **sysinternals**, I see that I have a "PATH NOT FOUND" error on those following paths:

- `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\META-INF\xfire\services.xml`
- `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\MyWebService\WEB-INF\META-INF\xfire\services.xml`
- `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\MyWebService\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\xfire\services.xml`

While the file is stored in:

- `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\MyWebService\META-INF\xfire\services.xml`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like getRessources() is used to read your xml, so the file need to be in the classpath.

Just move or copy the META-INF in one of your project source directory (i guess src or src/main...).

Comment: I found a workaround to solve my problem, so i cannot verify if your answer is correct. I'll leave it open until someone with the same problem can confirm it does work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where the META-INF folder had to stay within the WEB-INF ... this way up, you can keep your normal folders.
try this...

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>XFire</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireConfigurableServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>../META-INF/xfire/services.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Force the location of the file you need. In this case, I used **".. \"** to go up one level. This is done in ***web.xml***